# Angular material table access tbody

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, html-tbody

I'm using `mat-table` from `@angular/material` in one of my projects. And I need to access `<tbody>`

```
    <table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="someSource">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let some">{{some.field}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>

      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

    </table>
```

It generates HTML like this:
[image]

My question is: how can I access `tbody` tag to add some project-specific attributes?

It's not for CSS styling. Otherwise, it would be simple. I just need it to have `attr="value"`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below. Use `ViewChild` and angular lifecycle hook `AfterViewInit`

### Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9f4s99?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

**In the template file**

```
<table #testtable mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"> // --> Observe the template reference variable

    ...

</table>
```

**In the ts file**

```
export class TableBasicExample implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('testtable', {
    read: ElementRef
  }) tble: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tble.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody').setAttribute('data-title', 'Sivakumar Tadisetti');
    console.log(this.tble.nativeElement.querySelector('tbody'));
  }
}
```